# Extend a class with a concrete implementation of File

Tags: dart

I want to extend a class from File. File is abstract and I don't want to implement all the methods, so I searched for an implementation and found _File but this implementation is private.

Is there a class where it is possible to easy extend a File?

Comment: Could you describe *why* you want to do this?

Comment: And you cannot use extension methods? https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods